# Folium - KeyErrors

Tags: python, geospatial, folium

I'm currently trying to plot AirBnb locations in Paris using `folium`. My code is as below:

```
f = folium.Figure(width = 800, 
                  height = 500)
map = folium.Map(location = [48.8569421129686, 2.3503337285332204], # Coords for Paris 
                 zoom_start = 10, 
                 tiles = 'CartoDB positron').add_to(f)

for index in range(0, len(df4)-1):
    lat = df4['latitude'][index]
    long = df4['longitude'][index]
    temp = lat, long
    folium.Marker(temp, marker_icon = 'cloud').add_to(map)

map
```

df4 is structured with the following columns:

```
Index(['id', 'name', 'host_id', 'host_since', 'host_location',
       'host_acceptance_rate', 'host_is_superhost', 'host_neighbourhood',
       'neighbourhood_cleansed', 'latitude', 'longitude', 'property_type',
       'room_type', 'accommodates', 'bedrooms', 'beds', 'price',
       'minimum_nights', 'maximum_nights', 'number_of_reviews',
       'review_scores_rating', 'review_scores_accuracy',
       'review_scores_communication', 'review_scores_location',
       'review_scores_value'],
      dtype='object')
```

Why am I getting KeyError: 6 when I attempt to run my code? I attempted to use an if statement to catch index 6, but then I got KeyError 10. The data is formatted correctly, and all of the latitudes and longitudes are formatted uniformly. Why is it getting hung up on random rows?

Comment: Can you present reproducible data? Posting that and the full text of the error as well might speed up the resolution.

Comment: I searched for equivalent data and found [this](https://public.opendatasoft.com/explore/dataset/airbnb-listings/export/?). The column names are similar. You have a large number of cases, how many cases of data do you want to handle?

Comment: @r-beginners Data is from http://insideairbnb.com/get-the-data (Paris). The total number of cases is about 44k rows.

Comment: I checked the data, which file name is the 44k data?

Comment: @r-beginners listings.csv.gz.  I sliced the data to exclude some price outliers - it was originally about 65k rows, sliced down to 44k (as well as removing some of the columns). However, nothing about the latitude and longitude columns were changed.

Comment: Perhaps you forgot to reset index after removing NaN? I think you need to re-index with the latest data frame.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case, it is better to use the [`iterrows()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html) method from the Pandas dataframe to iterate over the rows of the dataframe :

```py
for row in df4.iterrows():
    lat = row[1]['latitude']
    long = row[1]['longitude']
    temp = lat, long
    folium.Marker(temp, marker_icon = 'cloud').add_to(map)
```